# Unity3D Instantiate works when not all conditions are met

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, instantiation

This script should spawn object after clicking on other object which is closer than hitRange and has tag "Block". The problem is that it always spawns new object after pushing LMB, also when needed conditions weren't met.

```
#pragma strict

var blockName : String;
private static var blockToPlace : Rigidbody;
var hitRange : float;
private var hit : RaycastHit;
var blockLayer : int = 8;
private var hitBlock : boolean;


function Update(){
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        blockToPlace = EditorUtility.InstantiatePrefab(AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Models/Blocks/"+blockName+".prefab", Rigidbody)) as Rigidbody;
        hitBlock = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, hit, Mathf.Infinity, blockLayer);
        if(hitBlock == true){
            if(hit.collider.tag == "Block"){
                if(hit.distance < hitRange){
                    var block : Rigidbody;
                    block = Instantiate(blockToPlace,hit.normal+hit.transform.position,Quaternion.identity) as Rigidbody;
                    hitBlock = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a hard time with the same problem myself.  [Layers](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) arn't exactly integers but rather bitshifts.

Watch this very nice video on layermasks: [www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8mAjwn-MB8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8mAjwn-MB8)

```
var blockLayer : int = 8;
```

should be

```
var blockLayer : int = 1 << 8;
```

Comment: @JWPL Be sure to accept an answer if it satisfactorily solves your problem, so your question is marked as answered.

Comment: @JWPL no problem, glad i helped someone

Comment: @JWPL also, consider programming in c#.  Unityscript is not as popular among unity developers and asset creators.